# Creating Square Buffer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer

I have a rectangular polygon I want to create another polygon that is 200 metres bigger in each direction from the original.

Is there a way to create a square buffer around the original polygon or another method to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the "*Miter*" **Join style**.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: For extra info : this is only available for QGIS 3.X. There's no options as this one in the buffer tool of QGIS 2.18.

Answer (score 5):

I recently wanted to do the same thing as the OP, but rather than irregular-shaped buffers of irregular polygons, I wanted actual squares. Here is an approach I used in QGIS 3.16, I hope it might be useful for others:

1. Create polygon centroids
2. Buffer centroid points by desired distance.
3. Use the 'Bounding boxes' tool in the Processing tool box

[image]