# Creating evenly spaced grid for QGIS composer to show overlap in Map?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping

I would like to create an evenly spaced, overlapping grid so that I can use the QGIS ATLAS to display a large mapping extent with a little bit of overlap between each image of the Composer.

I am working in QGIS 2.18.14 and have not been able to figure this one out.

I have tried using the 'Grids for Atlas' Plug-in but it does not give the option to set a uniform Extent when using its dynamic grid option.

Comment: do the techniques discussed in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/how-to-determine-neighbouring-tile-ids-in-qgis help?

Answer (score 5):

Use the "Create Grid" tool to create a grid of polygons.

[image]

Add a buffer to the polygon grid with the "Fixed Distance Buffer" tool. The buffer layer will have rounded corners. (In QGIS 3.0, square corners are possible by using a mitered join style. [square buffer in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277309/81764))

[image]

[image]

Use the buffer layer for the atlas coverage layer.

---

Or, you can skip creating a buffer, and use the grid as the atlas coverage layer with a margin around each feature.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this approach but by using the buffer the scale is increased and I need the Scale to remain at exactly 1:500. I have got the size of grid extents I need from creating a uniform grid at my defined composer extent using 'grids for atlas' plugin but I cant find a way of making them overlap a small amount without loosing this precise scale that is required.

Comment: There's no way to make an existing grid overlap without changing its size. You need to start with a smaller grid than what you want. Then increase the size of the cells to your desired cell size.

Answer (score 1):

You could to use atlas.
In atlas define the layer in "Coverage layer" and then[image]
In map item define "Controlled by atlas" and use "Margin around feature"
[image]

In QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.0 is the same procedure